# Conditionally adding space + string - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have written a quick `name` model method which returns a user's name based on what fields are present.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name,
    presence: true,
    length: {
      maximum: 64,
    }

  validates :last_name,
    length: {
      maximum: 64,
    }

  def name
    "#{self.first_name}#{" #{self.last_name}" if self.last_name.present?}"
  end
end
```

If only the `first_name` field is present, it should return:

```
=> "Joe"
```

If both, `first_name` and `last_name` fields are present, then it should return:

```
=> "Joe Bloggs"
```

The above code work, but i feel it can be cleaned up alot.

Is the a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of [**`squish`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish).

It removes all whitespaces from both ends of the string and also changes multiple spaces to one.

```
def name
  "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}".squish
end
```

Also, as it is an instance method you can remove `self`

```
def name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}".squish
end
```

Eg.

```
" foo   bar ".squish
#=> "foo bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach I take is:

```
[
  element_1,
  element_2,
  ...
  element_n
].compact.join(" ")
```

For data cleansing purposes you might:

```
[
  element_1,
  element_2,
  ...
  element_n
].map(&:squish).map(&:presence).compact.join(" ")
```

If you were instead making a list then in Rails you might try:

```
[
  element_1,
  element_2,
  ...
  element_n
].map(&:squish).map(&:presence).compact.to_sentence
```

... which would give you an internationalised string of the form:

```
"a, b, c, and d"
```